# Unable to debug project in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swift3, xcode8.2

I'm trying to debug my swift's project using breakpoints in Xcode 8.2.1
but when compiler arrive at line that i want to debug it, Xcode shows me below codes instead of my swift codes.

what can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure Debug -> Debug WorkFlow -> Always Show Disassembly is turned off.